# How to pass parameter into docker container and update file in container with passed parameter

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker, am trying to pass the local hostname ($Hostname) into docker container and change an entry of configuration file in a container with the new `$Hostname`.

I added a command in dockerfile as below:

```
RUN echo $Hostname >> /etc/***.config
```

and running docker from image

`run -e $Hosname='cat /etc/hostname' ...`

However, the `$Hostname` in the container is container's hostname instead of local host's. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The hostname of the container is actually one of the few things you *can't* change using normal methods. This is because the docker engine needs to know it's controlling this in order to handle linking and networks.

To set the hostname in a way that docker engine respects, do this:

```
docker run --hostname myhostname imagename
```

The [Network Settings](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/network-settings) section in the docs explain how this works

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking; the `-e` flag sets the specified environment variable at invocation time.

Try this instead:

```
docker run -e PARENT_HOSTNAME=${HOSTNAME} ...
```

(see @code_monk's answer for the specifics about setting the containers hostname to the same as the docker host)

I don't think you usually need or want the docker host hostname in the container, but that will set the environment variable in the container.